# How to use a loop to count the occurrence of a particular string in an Array

Tags: c#

I made two arrays using:

```
 string[] teamNames = File.ReadAllLines("Teams.txt")
 string[] champions = File.ReadAllLines("WorldSeriesWinners.txt")
```

I have the first array inside of the construct so that the `ListBox` shows up with the opening of the program.

The first array is then put into a `ListBox` from which a user can select a name of a team. Once this team's name is selected, that name should be counted in the second array and the count integer is increased by one if the name is found if not the loop should move to the next item in the array until all items are looked at.

I created the loop and I receive a value of zero for my count no matter what I select. I am not sure of what is causing this issue. From what I have checked, both arrays are working fine, but I believe my sequential search is not doing it's job correctly.

I have tried using a foreach and a for loop. Both have the same issue.

```
using System.IO;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string[] teamNames = File.ReadAllLines("Teams.txt");//Put team names into array for the list box
        listBox1.Sorted = true;//Sort list box
        foreach (string name in teamNames)//Puts array into listbox
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(name);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] champions = File.ReadAllLines("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");//Puts names of teams winning from 1903 to 2012

        int arrayLength = champions.Length; //Total length of champions list.
        int count = 0; //To count how many times a team has won
        int index = 0; //To process through the index
        string countedAmount = "";//To make my count into string.

        string selectedTeam = "";//To put listbox selection into string
        listBox1.SelectedItem = selectedTeam;//Assigning listbox item to string
        /*for (int i = 0; i<arrayLength; i++)
        {
            if(selectedTeam == champions[i])
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        }*/

        foreach (string name in champions)
        {
            if(selectedTeam == champions[index] )
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                index++;
            }
        }

        countedAmount = count.ToString();//Count into string
        MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem + " won the world series " + countedAmount + " times!");//Display count
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You assign the `listBox1.SelectedItem` to your variable, instead of reading the value, and you initialize `selectedTeam` to `""` for no reason. Unless constrained by if logic, always, always initialize to your desired value: `string selectedTeam = listBox1.SelectedItem;`'

Comment: You should be assigning the selectedTeam variable with listbox selection not vice versa.

Comment: @NetMage

Sorry, I failed to mention that I originally I had:

     if (listBox1.SelectedItem == champions[i])

and it would say unintended reference comparison and the IDE tells me to cast the left hand side to string CS0252

when I do the following, the IDE tells me (cs0266)
     string selectedTeam = listBox1.SelectedItem;

Comment: Where exactly is your selected item? The value is no where inside the method you have specified. You should be getting it from the EventArgs right? You have called button_click but where is the chosen value being fetched? Also, please do not use '==', use selectedItem.Equals(champions[index])

Comment: **Use a debugger**. If you stepped through the code in a debugger you would quickly see that one of your variables has the wrong value.

Comment: @Minu your suggestion worked! :)

if(listBox1.SelectedItem.Equals(champions[i]))

Everyone else's suggestions made more errors which I am not sure how to fix. (that's why I didn't assign the listbox's item directly to a string.)

and Eric Lippert I am not sure how to interpret what the debugger is saying so I came here for help. I have looked at similar problems other people have had, and the answers are way beyond my understanding unfortunately.

I had to forgo the foreach loop since it gave me wonky numbers (idk why). But the for loop works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Please upvote if u feel that was the right suggestion :)

Comment: If you got error CS0252 you used `if (... = ...` and __not__ `if (... == ...` as that is the meaning of the error. `ListBox.SelectedItem` is of type `object`, you must always watch your types in C#. `listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` would work.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting listBox1.SelectedItem to an empty string selectedTeam.

```
 string selectedTeam = "";//To put listbox selection into string
 listBox1.SelectedItem = selectedTeam;//Assigning listbox item to string
```

Instead you should be assigning listBox1.SelecteItem to a string.